# navigationBarTitle works on iOS not MacOS apps

Tags: macos, swiftui

the following code compiles and runs just fine on iOS and Catalyst.  But when I run it in a macOS app it get an error.  Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong.  macOS Catalina version 10.15.3, Xcode version 11.3.1.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Item #1")
                Text("Item #2")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Add"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

here is the error that I get,

`Value of type 'List<Never, TupleView<(Text, Text)>>' has no member 'navigationBarTitle'`

Answer (score 8):

Switch to `.navigationTitle("Title")` and you'll find this now works on macOS, in Big Sur and above.

Comment: What about Catalina? No titles on Catalina?

Answer (score 2):

Title bar is not available on macOS. Here is interface declaration:

> ```
> @available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> @available(OSX, unavailable)
> extension View {
>
>     /// Hides the navigation bar for this view.
>     ///
>     /// This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible
>     /// within a `NavigationView`.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameters:
>     ///     - hidden: A Boolean value that indicates whether to hide the
>     ///       navigation bar.
>     @available(OSX, unavailable)
>     public func navigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View
>
>
>     /// Configures the title in the navigation bar for this view.
>     ///
>     /// This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible
>     /// within a `NavigationView`.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameters:
>     ///     - title: A description of this view to display in the navigation
>     ///       bar.
>     @available(OSX, unavailable)
>     public func navigationBarTitle(_ title: Text) -> some View
>
>
>     /// Configures the title in the navigation bar for this view.
>     ///
>     /// This modifier only takes effect when this view is inside of and visible
>     /// within a `NavigationView`.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameters:
>     ///     - titleKey: A key to a localized description of this view to display
>     ///       in the navigation bar.
>     @available(OSX, unavailable)
>     public func navigationBarTitle(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey) -> some View
> ```

Comment: I'm confused if its not available what is the interface that you posted?  is that some pseudo code or something like that?

Comment: It is copy-past from SwiftUI interface declaration. You can CMD-CTRL-Click on `navigationBarTitle` and see it yourself. Updated with full corresponding View extension.

Comment: Thank you was unclear on the syntax had never seen it. I will play with that feature tonight when I get home. Any idea if they have plans of making it available? Also I’m learning swift with swiftui never really used the uikit appkit paradigm so I’m wondering is navigation view available on appkit or is that a swiftui thing.

Comment: It is iOS thing, there is no such in AppKit, that's why it is not available.

Comment: i hope they plan on extending it because they made it available on swiftui which is supposed to work on all of the platforms.  but then they dont implement these features.  what is the recommended way of doing navigationview type interfaces in swiftui for macos apps.  Sorry the documentation on this is really bad since almost all tutorials focus on ios.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here searching for a portable solution.
A fast solution (I derived from  https://fatbobman.medium.com/building-adaptable-swiftui-applications-for-multiple-platforms-964624fa7b2) can be:

```
extension View {
#if os(macOS)
    @ViewBuilder
    func navigationBarTitle(_ title: String) -> some View {
        navigationTitle(title)
    }
#endif
}
```

Another advantage is to  fix a LOT of occurrences without polluting Your code with many #if os(xxxx)

Hope can help others.